# Wrong Json response on calling the WCF web service

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, wcf-ria-services, nsjsonserialization

Hii all i am facing the strange problem while dealing with the wcf json web-services.. The same web service when get called from android, It returns the valid JSON but when i am calling from the iOS i am getting the null and only null, I tried from all the way i can, But i am not getting my mistake .. My code for calling the wcf web service is as follow.

```
    NSString *urlStringRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",urlPath,parameterName]; //its my URL to connect to web server.

       NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStringRequest]];
       [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
       [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

       NSError *error = nil;
       NSURLResponse *response = nil;
       NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

       NSArray *jsonArrayOne = [self parseJsonResult:result];

       NSLog(@"Json Resul: %@", jsonArrayOne);
```

The Function parseJsonResult is as follows

```
     - (id)parseJsonResult:(NSData *)result
    {
        if( ! result)
            return nil;
        NSError *error = nil;


        jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: result options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];

        if (!jsonArray) {
            NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", error);
        } else {
            for(NSDictionary *item in jsonArray) {
                NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
            }
        }
        return jsonArray;
}
```

The url is like

```
http://xxx/xxx/xxx.svc/login?parameter={\"username\":\"abc.xyz\",\"password\":\"Password123\"}
```

and calling this wcf web-service from android returns the proper json response but calling from the iOS returning the null . where have i mistaken, Please help me.

Comment: Does your server require `User-Agent` header to be set in the request? Also print the `error` after request completes, to check if any error info is available.

Comment: Try logging your NSData *result

Comment: NSLog the error in case the returned result is nil. This might give a hint about the issue. Do not use the synchronous convenient methods, use NSURLConnection in asynchronous mode, that is implement the delegate methods.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper : thanks your trick made ma work it was throwing the bad url error, i encoded the url with stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding and i got the out put but again the wrong json , From android it gives the out put  {
    "LoginResult": "{\"result\":{\"success\":\"1\",\"data\":{\"userid\":\"33\"}}}"
} which is the valid JSON but for me the response is like.. {
    LoginResult = "{\"result\":{\"success\":\"1\",\"data\":{\"userid\":\"33\"}}}";
}   which is not valid JOSN.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and when you get right JSOn then c & p your json into [jsonformatter block](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) then click on proceed button

```
-(void)yourMethod
{
    NSString *urlStringRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",urlPath,parameterName]; //its my URL to connect to web server.

       NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStringRequest] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];
       [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

       NSString *stringBoundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY---This_Is_ThE_BoUnDaRyy---pqo";
       NSString *headerBoundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",stringBoundary];

       [request addValue:headerBoundary forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

       NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];

      // media part
       [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

       [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

       [request setHTTPBody:postBody];

       NSHTTPURLResponse* response =[[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] init];
       NSError* error = [[NSError alloc] init] ;

      //synchronous filling of data from HTTP POST response
      NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:dataRqst returningResponse:&response error:&error];

       //convert data into string
       NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[responseData bytes] length:[responseData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

      NSLog(@"responseString %@ ",responseString);

    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", error);
    } else {
        if([[[[responseString objectForKey:@"LoginResult"] objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"success"] isEqualToString:@"1"];)
         {
            jsonArray= [[[[responseString objectForKey:@"LoginResult"] objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"success"] objectForKey:@"data"];
             NSLog(@"jsonArray : %@",jsonArray);
         }
    }
    return jsonArray;
}
```

I hope it helps you...!

Comment: Why do you need to include `SBJson` files if you use `NSJSONSerialization`? ;)

Comment: Hi iShwar, Have a look on my updated code. Please let me know if any problem occurs. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how trying this code could be of any help.

Comment: @chandan :hi i was not geting the o/p coz of bad url error i resolve that by encoding the url with UTF-8 , But now i am geting the o/p { LoginResult = "{\"result\":{\"success\":\"1\",\"data\":{\"userid\":\"33\"}}}"; } which is wrong JSON,the same web service caled from android returns the { "LoginResult": "{\"result\":{\"success\":\"1\",\"data\":{\"userid\":\"33\"}}}" }  which is the correct o/p, and, Ya i have integrated your code instead of mine, so the out put i have showed you is the nslog of  NSLog(@"dict : %@",dictIs). and the NSLog(@"dict : %@",jsonArray); is giving me null.

Comment: Hi iShwar , You might be doing wrong with send request. So change it according to updated code

Comment: @chandan : i changed my code snippet with yours totally, steel i am getting the same out put as { LoginResult = "{\"result\":{\"success\":\"1\",\"data\":{\"userid\":\"33\"}}}"; } , :( if i nslog this as a NSLog(@"%@",_dict=dictIs[@"LoginResult"]); i am getting the out put as a dictionary like {"result":{"success":"1","data":{"userid":"33","username":"Shyam Deore"}}} which is valid json, now how should i get the each item from this.

Comment: Hi iShwar , i think Json it valid . You are doing mistake to read it. Try my updated code and copy paste your json inside jsonformatter link. I have updated my code according to your Json format. It would works fine. Thanks

Comment: @chandan : hi chandan juz help me at once i am having the json string like {"LoginResult":"{\"result\":{\"success\":\"1\",\"data\":{\"userid\":\"31\",\"username\":\"Shyam Deore\"}}}"} and i want to parse this , i used the sjon parser for that then i am getting the response like {
    LoginResult = "{\"result\":{\"success\":\"1\",\"data\":{\"userid\":\"31\",\"username\":\"Shyam Deore\"}}}";
}  which is the dictionary, where LoginResult is a key and remaining is the value.. what should i do to fetch the all other values.. how should i get them individually.. please give me some way..

Comment: @chandan : Hi Sir, i have explain in details here , please give me some time for that.. http://pastebin.com/qGVfTwSJ

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30981/discussion-between-chandan-and-ishwar)

Comment: @chandan : Yes Sir,I just let you know about.

Comment: It was diff. issue Sir, The String I was sending to parse was in double quotes, which was the value for key LoginResult , so though its the part of nsdictionary coz of the double quotes the it was considered ad a string, and hence was not returning me the dictionary.. Anyways thanks for your help and valuable time. Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome ishwar , So my answer was right to parse. It's m,istake in your web service. You can award me by accepting and vote up to my answer. Thanks